# Does Model Package Editor from Master Data Services have a limit on the Size of package you can edit?

Tags: sql-server-2017, master-data-services, master-data-management

I am trying to use the Model Package Editor wizard in SQL Server 2017.

It works fine for smaller packages and I am able to select the relevant objects that I want to keep in my package. the largest I was able to open was around 900mb.

However when I try to edit one that is 3GB. It does not show me any of the objects and there is just a blank page.

Is it not able to handle large files ? Is there a way to fix this ?

I tried to use the wizard to edit my package, but it left me with that blank screen. I expected to see a list of objects that I can select from.

Comment: Don't use images and external links, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask